# Apache Proxy Server - Hopefully an easy fix

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, proxy, opensuse

I am having issues with using relative directories from within the server that my proxy server redirects too.

Lets call my top level server that provides the proxy "Proxy", and the first sub server "Client1".

Proxy is setup to redirect /client1 to localhost:81/client1 (This works fine)

Client1 has the following directory structure:

```
/srv/www/
    /client1 (The root dir for the server)
        /system
        /3rdparty
        /client1 (Redirect to this dir)
            - test.php (This renders)
```

The issue I have, is that within `test.php` I use `../system/somefile` and `../3rdparty/jquery.js`. These fail to resolve.

Example:

```
- navigate to `www.example.com/client1` (test.php loads)
- test.php loads
- check console see errors: `www.example.com/system/somefile` cannot be found (404)
```

Does anyone know what I need to do so that the `../` gets passed along to the Client1 server, rather than being evaluated on the Proxy server?

My proxy pass settings:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib64/apache2-prefork/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

 <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

# INSTANCE v01 for client1
ProxyPass /client1 https://localhost:81/client1
ProxyPassReverse /client1 https://localhost:81/client1
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are requests for URLs that don't start with `/client1` processed? Do you have a `DocumentRoot` or any other `ProxyPass` directives?

Answer (score 1):

`../` is evaluated by your browser, not by the server.